# Can't start MongoDB , mongod is always stop/waiting

Tags: 16.04, mongodb

I try to run v2.6.10 on Ubuntu 16.04 server:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

And get the result:

```
mongod start/running, process 67725
```

But when I check the status I get:

```
mongod stop/waiting
```

The content of log:

```
2017-09-10T07:47:16.528+0200 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5493 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ns1
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.10
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] build info: Linux lgw01-12 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_58
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/data/db", journal: { enable$
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod ins$
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] dbexit:
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2017-09-10T07:47:16.530+0200 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
2017-09-10T07:47:16.530+0200 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: These two problems are not the same

Comment: Is that's so then edit your question, explain why it's not a duplicate and link to the other question. It's at least related for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this log line it is a permissions issue.

> /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod ins$
>   2017-09-10T07:47:16.529+0200 [initandlisten] dbexit:

It appears that you changed the `dbpath` from the default `/var/lib/mongodb` in `/etc/mongodb.conf`

Fix the permissions and ownership on `/data/db`.  Assuming that you used a package the *user:group* should be *mongodb:mongodb* so the following commands should get it working in this custom location.

Change the permissions to mirror the package location:

```
sudo chmod 755 /data/db
```

Ensure that the directory ownership is the same as the official package:

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /data/db
```